# How to work with traits and abstract classes in php

Tags: php, static, abstract-class, traits

I am really confused with this and can't really find anything on it.

Take for instance:

```
<?php
trait T{
   public static $td;
   public static function getTd(){return self::$td;}
   public static function setTd($td){self::$td=$td;}
}

class A{
   use T;
}

abstract class B{
   use T;
}

class C extends B{
   
}

$a=new A;
$a->setTd('X');
echo $a->getTd();//'X'

echo (new C)->getTd();//null
?>
```

How come the last line is null?

Comment: I am gonna delete as I have got this all wrong

Comment: Welcome @Chika. According to [Class Abstraction](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php), php interpreter does not allocate memory for abstract Class. You can remove abstract reserved word for `B` and try again.

Comment: Alright, that is really good to know actually, thanks. But I think I got everything missed up and for some reason I was thinking that A and C are sharing 'td' because they are using the same trait. This is obviously wrong!